# Contact form doesn't accept non-Latin characters

Tags: php, validation, contact-form

For example, when someone put Greek characters in the NAME field on SEND the contact form returns with an error report.
So, how do I edit my contact form to accept non-Latin characters in both NAME & MESSAGE fields?

```
 function validation(){var contactname=document.forms["contactfrm"]["name"].value;var name_exp=/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/;if(contactname==''){swal("You forgot your name...", " ", "warning");document.forms["contactfrm"]["name"].focus();return false;}else if(!contactname.match(name_exp)){swal("Invalid name...", " ", "error");document.forms["contactfrm"]["name"].focus();return false;}var email=document.forms["contactfrm"]["email"].value; //var email_exp=/^[A-Za-z0-9\.-_\$]+@[A-Za-z]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
var email_exp=/^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;if(email==''){swal("You forgot to enter your email...", " ", "warning");document.forms["contactfrm"]["email"].focus();return false;} else if(!email.match(email_exp)){swal("Your email address is invalid...", " ", "error");document.forms["contactfrm"]["email"].focus();return false;}var message=document.forms["contactfrm"]["comments"].value; if(message==''){swal("No empty messages, please...", "warning");document.forms["contactfrm"]["comments"].focus();return false;}return true;}<?php if (isset($_GET["r"])){if($_GET["r"]=="1")echo('swal("Your message has been sent!", " ", "success");');else echo('swal("Your message failed to send...", " ", "error");');};?>
```

Comment: what "error report" ??

Comment: Sorry, I meant failure warning.

Comment: what "failure warning"? if you getting an error\notice form php post it, if your getting an error from somewhere else post that. This is programming, *specifics* matter

Comment: Are you using `iso-8859-1`? Maybe you need to go to UTF8 because your characters aren't supported?

Comment: @Dagon I edited my question to include the warning image.

Comment: @chris85 Applying 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' unfortunately, It didn't work.

Comment: nothing in the code you provided would produce that error. I'm guessing some js validation perhaps?

Comment: @Dagon I'm very clear! What you don't understand! 
When someone writes his name in Greek in the NAME field the message doesn't come into my inbox nor anywhere else because send has failed!

Comment: I 100% understand the problem, but the code you gave us simply cant produce this error -so how can we help?

Comment: @Dagon This is an edited sweetalert modal dialog. As I wrote before, "When someone writes his name in Greek in the NAME field the message doesn't come into my inbox nor anywhere else because send has failed!". That's the problem! I want my contact form to accept all characters, no matter what the nationality is... That's it!

Comment: well that's the first time you even mentioned the js. the issue is its validation, show us that code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101832/discussion-between-jim-and-dagon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i took apart the js of your site, find and remove this line:

```
else if(!contactname.match(name_exp)){swal("Invalid name..."," ","error");
```

that will let the name be anything (but not blank that's checked else where)

alternatively find

```
name_exp=/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/
```

and replace with

```
name_exp=/^*+$/
```

Comment: I prefer the second option but DreamWeaver shows syntax error...

Comment: does it like `name_exp=/^*$/`

Comment: Yes, it does! But I would like to force people to write a name.

Comment: empty is checked else where: `if(contactname==''){swal("You forgot your name...", " ", "warning")`

Comment: You mean to leave the name_exp blank?

Comment: not blank just a regular expression that allows anything -personally i would jut remove the check altogether, but you wanted it left in

Comment: It does work fine but still I want senders to include their names. This is a very important step!

Comment: @Jim i checked your site, if name is blank i get "You forgot your name..." as i mentored before, so whats the problem with that?

Comment: That happened because I reverted to my previous snippet.

Comment: your making it to hard to help you, i suspect i have taken you 99% of the way (you may want to reread some of the above); but i have to focus on my paid job. You can give credit or not.

Comment: Well, it doesn't do what exactly I want but because it works very good maybe someone other find it helpful! Thank you for your effort!